# Is there any way to replace the existing object inside JSON array with new object based on key

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a dynamic JSON array in below format,

```
let main_data = [
   {
      "client":[
         {
            "name":"aaaa",
            "count":"1",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"test3"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "name":"bbbb",
            "count":"9",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"test2"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "compute":[
         {
            "name":"cccc",
            "count":"6",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"test"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Here key "name" is unique. When updating a form, I will get an json array like below,

```
let new_data = [
   {
      "client":[
         {
            "name":"bbbb",
            "count":"1234",
               "type":{
                  "name":"updated_name"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I need to check the "name" in the json array in "main_data" and remove the existing one and update with the new "updated_data" into the "main_data". (no Jquery please)

Expected output,

```
let main_data = [
   {
      "client":[
         {
            "name":"aaaa",
            "count":"1",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"test3"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "name":"bbbb",
            "count":"123",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"updated_name"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "compute":[
         {
            "name":"cccc",
            "count":"6",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"test"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Is there any way to achive this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, what have you tried?

Comment: There is no "JSON array", you have an array literal.

Comment: I tried to take the index and remove the item from main_data and append the new data. But its not working as expected. I tried another way which Emrani suggested. Here is my fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/pu5wev07/

Comment: @kalaiyarasiM, Hope this is your final expected output https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/PoqLBgK   .. Look at console for your needed data.. Also your forked fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/bjwytmz3/

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, its working fine. Thank you

Comment: @ManirajMuruganAs its needed for dynamic, i added variable name and its not working. Throwing error. tried to solve, but not working. Here is my Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bg7Lyvut/1/

Comment: @kalaiyarasiMl, ```map()``` method is only for arrays.. Yesterday your requirement is something and today you  are changing to others.. Also why the same question is posted by another user?? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60984853/7785337

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Sorry. Actually format has been changed. This is final format. Could you please help with this?

Comment: Those people are my teammates. They dont know i posted here. As we are not getting answers, they posted i guess. Please help with me this issue

Comment: @kalaiyarasiM, Cool.. Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/1hLcvnw6/

Comment: @kalaiyarasiM, Also posted answer in another question, do accept it if it resolves your team issue..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan Working like charm. Thanks a lot for your help at the right time

Comment: @kalaiyarasiM, Glad to help you ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
let main_data = [{
    client: [{
            name: "aaaa",
            count: "1",
            filter: {
                type: {
                    name: "test3"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: "bbbb",
            count: "9",
            filter: {
                type: {
                    name: "test2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    compute: [{
        name: "cccc",
        count: "6",
        filter: {
            type: {
                name: "test"
            }
        }
    }]
}
];
let new_data = [{
client: [{
    name: "bbbb",
    count: "1234",
    filter: {
        type: {
            name: "updated_name"
        }
    }
}]
}];

const res = main_data.map((item, index) => {
if (item.client) {
    const clients = item.client.map(client => {
        if (client.name === new_data[0].client[0].name) {
            client = new_data[0].client[0];
        }
        return client;
    });
    return {
        client: clients
    };
}
return item;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Sorry, when i am adding variable name instead of calling it directly, its not working.

Comment: Sorry, not working. Dont know what I am missing. Please check my Fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/eyvojfL2/

Answer (score 0):

There may very well be a fancy way to get this done but one can always just find the matching item  and replace it. eg.

```js
   let main_data = [
        {
            "client": [
                {
                    "name": "aaaa",
                    "count": "1",
                    "filter": {
                        "type": {
                            "name": "test3"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "bbbb",
                    "count": "123",
                    "filter": {
                        "type": {
                            "name": "updated_name"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "compute": [
                {
                    "name": "cccc",
                    "count": "6",
                    "filter": {
                        "type": {
                            "name": "test"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    let new_data = [
        {
            "client": [
                {
                    "name": "bbbb",
                    "count": "1234",
                    "type": {
                        "name": "updated_name"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    console.log("before:" + JSON.stringify(main_data));

    newItem = new_data[0]["client"][0];
    mainDataList = main_data[0]["client"];

    for (i = 0; i < mainDataList.length; i++) {
        if (mainDataList[i].name == newItem.name) {
            mainDataList[i] = newItem;
        }
    }
    console.log("after:" + JSON.stringify(main_data));
```

will output

```
before:[{"client":[{"name":"aaaa","count":"1","filter":{"type":{"name":"test3"}}},{"name":"bbbb","count":"123","filter":{"type":{"name":"updated_name"}}}]},{"compute":[{"name":"cccc","count":"6","filter":{"type":{"name":"test"}}}]}]
after:[{"client":[{"name":"aaaa","count":"1","filter":{"type":{"name":"test3"}}},{"name":"bbbb","count":"1234","type":{"name":"updated_name"}}]},{"compute":[{"name":"cccc","count":"6","filter":{"type":{"name":"test"}}}]}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple way to do this, let's say your new data is at variable `newData`:

```
main_data.client.filter(item => item.name === newData.name).push(newData)
```

Comment: I tried the same method, but its not working. Here is https://jsfiddle.net/pu5wev07/

Comment: in your fiddle, @kalaiyarasiM since the main_data is an array of objects, you should first specify the index, then use the dot operator to select the object member,
change `main_data.client` to `main_data[0].client` it will work.

Comment: @kalaiyarasiM–don't post your code elsewhere and link to it from a comment to an answer. Put it in the question.