# Is there any way to modify the objects dynamically by comparing on key value pair

Tags: javascript, json

I am having a dynamic JSON array in below format,

```
let main_object = [
   {
      "apple":[
         {
            "name":"aaaa",
            "count":"1",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"test3"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "name":"bbbb",
            "count":"9",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"test2"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "orange":[
         {
            "name":"cccc",
            "count":"6",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"test"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Here key "name" is unique. When updating a form, I will get an json array like below,

```
let updated_data = {
       "orange":[
          {
             "name":"cccc",
             "count":"1234",
             "type":{
                "name":"updated_name"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

I need to check the "name" in the json array in "main_object" and remove the existing one and update with the new "updated_data" into the "main_object".

Expected output,

```
let main_object = [
   {
      "client":[
         {
            "name":"aaaa",
            "count":"1",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"test3"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "name":"bbbb",
            "count":"9",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"test2"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "orange":[
         {
            "name":"cccc",
            "count":"1234",
            "filter":{
               "type":{
                  "name":"updated_name"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I tried to use below method, but its throwing map of undefined. Dont know what I am missing. Is there any way to achive this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Here is Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ynx6oqrp/

```
let rtype = 'orange';

const altered = 
  main_object.map((level1,i) => {
   const data = main_object[0].rtype.map((item,index) => {
      if(item.name === updated_data[0].rtype[0].name){
          item = updated_data[0].rtype[0];
       }
       return item;
      })
    if(level1.rtype){
      level1.rtype = data;
    }
    return level1;
  })

console.log(altered);
```

Comment: would something like assign work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: There is no such thing as a _JSON Object_. There's JSON (the string representation of an Object) and there are Objects (a key-value collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map method is only for array and hence you need to make the map over `level1[rtype]` like,

```
level1[rtype].map()
```

Then to compare the name use,

```
if(item.name === updated_data[rtype][0].name) {
       item = updated_data[rtype];
}
```

And working snippet as follows,

```js
let main_object = [
       {
          "apple":[
             {
                "name":"aaaa",
                "count":"1",
                "filter":{
                   "type":{
                      "name":"test3"
                   }
                }
             },
             {
                "name":"bbbb",
                "count":"9",
                "filter":{
                   "type":{
                      "name":"test2"
                   }
                }
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "orange":[
             {
                "name":"cccc",
                "count":"6",
                "filter":{
                   "type":{
                      "name":"test"
                   }
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
    
    
    
    let updated_data = {
    "orange":[
       {
          "name":"cccc",
          "count":"1234",
          "type":{
             "name":"updated_name"
          }
       }
    ]
 }

let rtype = 'orange';

const altered = 
  main_object.map((level1,i) => {

  if(level1[rtype] !== undefined){
     const data = level1[rtype].map((item,index) => {
     if(item.name === updated_data[rtype][0].name) {
       item = updated_data[rtype];
     }
     return item;
  })
      if(level1[rtype] !== undefined){
      level1[rtype] = data;
    }
  }
    return level1; 
  })

console.log(altered);
```

> [**Forked JsFiddle here ...**](https://jsfiddle.net/1hLcvnw6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
            let rtype = 'orange';
            main_object = main_object.map(function (item) {
                if(Object.keys(item).indexOf(rtype) > -1){
                    item[rtype][0]['filter']['type']['name'] = updated_data[rtype][0]['type']['name'];
                    return item
                }else {
                    return item
                }
            });
            console.log(main_object)
```